# Комбинация селекторов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня есть `DIV`, а внутри него параграф. Не могу сообразить как вывести текст из этого параграфа.

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
text=$(this).$('p');
alert(text)
})
```

Пробовал, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно будет так:

```
var text = $("p", this).html();
```

Comment: Либо `$(this).find('p').html()`.